# How to use custom WrkTaskIp.aspx page in custom sharepoint workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have created as custom task edit browser enabled Infopath form which successfully gets open when user clicks on Edit task. But by default it opens up in the **WrkTaskIP.aspx** page which is available in 12 hive..Layouts folder.

Now the default WrkTaskIP form provides two following options as hyperlinks
1. Delete item, and
2. A link to navigate to the task display form

I want to customize the OOB, WrkTaskIP page and associate that with my workflow.

How exactly can i achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got a custom task content type you can create a custom feature with an application page and make the task open the form in this page instead.

Copy the WkrTaskIP.aspx page from the 12 hive, modify the contents as you require and deploy this as an application page.

Then in your taskcontenttype.xml file point to your custom page by setting the Display or Edit values to the deployed location of your custom page:

```
<FormUrls...>
    <Display>_layouts/YourCompany/Workflow/YourWrkTaskIIP.aspx</Display>
    <Edit>_layouts/YourCompany/Workflow/YourWrkTaskIIP.aspx</Edit>
</FormUrls>
```